# Remove a item of a hierarchical list if item has no children

Tags: c#, linq

I have several objects thats belongs to another objects, like:

```
class Portal
{
    List<Group> Groups;
}

class Group
{
    List<User> Users;
}

class User
{
    List<Item> Items;
}

class Item
{
    ...
}
```

Now, suppose that, after call a function, I will receive a list like:

```
+ Portal A:
  + Group A1:
    + User A1:
      - Item A1
      - Item A2
    + User A2
  + Group A2
+ Portal B
  + Group B1
    + User B1
+ Portal C
  + Group C1
    + User C1
      - Item C1
```

Check that I have a user (**User A2**) that don't have Itens and I have a Group (**Group A2**) without user.

And, a more complicated situation: I have a Portal (**Portal B**) that have a group (**Group B1**) that have a user (**User B1**), but this user don't have any item, so this user (**User B1**) it's not valid, but now, the **Group B1** it's not valid too, because don't have any user, and so, the **Portal B1** don't have any group.

How can I made this list without the itens that don't have any child, like:

```
+ Portal A:
  + Group A1:
    + User A1:
      - Item A1
      - Item A2
+ Portal C
  + Group C1
    + User C1
      - Item C1
```

I can make this with a lot of for, do, while, foreach, etc...

But there's a solution with LINQ? Or something similar?

(The shorter the code, better).

Comment: Please show what you have tried? A few nested `foreach`/`for` + `.Any()` should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this code "works" for your specific scenario, I would not recommend using it as it's extremely unreadable, doesn't clearly convey the codes intended purpose, causes side-effects where there shouldn't be any and will be a pain for other maintainers to work with later and debug.

[Gilad Green's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367578/699426) is much more sensible :-)

However, having said that here is a version that satisfies your need for shortness using *pure* Linq.

```
var filteredPortals =
  portals.Where(
    p => (p.Groups = p.Groups.Where(
      g => (g.Users = g.Users.Where(
        u => u.Items.Any()
      ).ToList()).Any()
    ).ToList()).Any()
  ).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you indent that? It's coming out pretty wide on my iPhone.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Better?

Comment: tks! I liked more the code of @GilardGreen (for the same reasons you mentioned), but I asked for a shorter code!

Answer (score 1):

Though possible, linq is used for querying and not assigning. A readable solution uses both `foreach` and linq. For each level loop into the deeper level. At the end of the scope of each level filter the list to keep only those items that their nested loop has any items.

Better than explaining here is some code :)

```
foreach (var portal in portals)
{
    foreach (var group in portal.Groups)
    {
        //Keep only users with items
        group.Users = group.Users.Where(user => user.Items.Any()).ToList();
    }
    //Keep only groups with users
    portal.Groups = portal.Groups.Where(group => group.Users.Any()).ToList();
}
//Keep only portals with groups
portals = portals.Where(portal => portal.Groups.Any()).ToList();
```

Tested with the following input:

```
List<Portal> portals = new List<Portal>()
{
    //Will keep
    new Portal { Name = "a", Groups = new List<Group>
    {
        //Will keep
        new Group {  Users = new List<User> {  new User {  Items = new List<Item> { new Item()} } } },
        //Filtered
        new Group {  Users = new List<User> {  new User {  Items = new List<Item> () } } }
    } },
    //Will keep
    new Portal { Name = "b", Groups = new List<Group>
    {
        new Group {  Users = new List<User> 
        {  
            //Filtered
            new User {  Items = new List<Item> () },
            //Will keep 
            new User { Items = new List<Item> { new Item() } } 
        } }
    } },
    //Filtered
    new Portal { Groups = new List<Group>() }
};
```

Comment: Too bad those type don't implement some "common interface" (as they share a common " shape") it could have helped to leverage the duplication